# GHC 7.10.1, Leksah 0.15.0.1 debugging problems

Tags: leksah

I have a series of questions relating to debugging in Leksah, which does not seem to work, or maybe it is only me who is not using it correctly. I don't know.

I present the questions in a screencast because it is much more clearer to present it like that then in writing+pictures : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeB8j_Viwrg

Main question : is this buggy behaviour of Leksah or is it only me who is not using it correctly ? If it is latter, how should I use the debug features correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks heaps for making this video, it makes it much easier to follow what is going on!

I think the problem is that Haskell is really lazy.  When you evaluated `n` at the very start of the debug session (before the video starts but you can see it in the log pane at the start of the video) `n` was replaced with the result (in this case 17).  When you ask it to step into it there is nothing left to step into it is as iff you just had `n=17` in the code.

Try restarting the the debug session or pressing Ctrl+B to force a `:reload` of the code.  After you do this `n` should be an unevaluated thunk again and you should be able to step through it or set breakpoints in code it uses.

Comment: I tried, restarting the debug session did the trick. Many thanks for the info.